# Call python-script from C# - Error with encoding UTF-8 in python.exe

Tags: python, c#, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to call a Python script in C#. For this Iuse the Process. The code looks like this:

```
const string cmd = @"C:\Python38\python.exe";
const string args = @"D:\path\to\script\app3.py";

ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @"C:\Python38\python.exe";
        start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, args);
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        start.RedirectStandardError = true;
        start.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; #I tried this to fix the problem
        start.StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; #I tried this to fix the problem
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        start.EnvironmentVariables["PYTHONUTF8"] = "1"; #I tried this to fix the problem

        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(errors);
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.Write(result);
            }
        }
```

I get the following error at the line `string errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();`

*File "C:\Python38\python.exe", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file C:\Python38\python.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details*

Presumption is that the Process opens CMD in the background and CMD uses a different encoding. How can I define the encoding for the process. Or is it something else entirely?

Since the error occurs in python.exe and not in my Python script, I assume that the error is not in the Python script itself, but in CMD or a Python configuration.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to execute`python.exe` with `python.exe`.

Comment: `python.exe` is a script interpreter and is usually executed for that reason with a script file name as argument, i.e. something like `C:\Python38\python.exe "C:\Path to\Python Script.py"`. There is specified with `start.FileName = @"C:\Python38\python.exe";` the executable to run. But what is `start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, args);` which defines the arguments for the executable to run? Where are `cmd` and `args` defined? Please read the Microsoft documentation for the [Process class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process).

Comment: Please note that there is __not__ executed `cmd.exe` in the background. That would be done only on using `start.UseShellExecute = true;` which would result in running `cmd.exe` with option `/c` and the command line defined in C# code as additional arguments. But this is not necessary here. It is much better to run `python.exe` using the `Process` class without `cmd.exe`.

Comment: The `Process` class is a C# wrapper class for the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) used by all Windows applications capable starting an executable like `cmd.exe`, `cscript.exe`, `explorer.exe`, `powershell.exe`, `wscript.exe`, etc. without or with using [STARTUPINFO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow). So your code is correct with exception of a correct definition of which Python script to run by Python.

Comment: Hi @Mofi. Thank you for your input. Sorry I forgot to describe the two variables cmd and args. So `cmd =@"C:\Python38\python.exe"; ` and args is the path to the pyhon-script I want to call. (I will edit my question)

Comment: @ManuelWolf Well, then the mistake is `start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, args);` which should be just `start.Arguments = args;` to run `C:\Python38\python.exe` as defined with `start.FileName = @"C:\Python38\python.exe";` with the Python script file name as defined with `start.Arguments = args;`. Please note the string assigned to `start.Arguments` must be with `"` on fully qualified Python script file name containing a space.

Comment: Nice. Thank you very much. It works with just `start.Arguments = args;`